# Best way to find smallest value from array containing objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wants to find out the object which holds the smallest value of a key in an array.

```
var tempArr = [{name: 'john', age: 23}, {name: 'jonny', age: 27}, {name: 'roony', age: 13}, {name: 'david', age: 33}];
```

I want the result to be

```
{name: 'roony', age: 13}
```

without using for loop is there any direct way to find out the result, like we can do for plain array

for example: 
if array is -

```
var arr = [11,4,22,3,5,55];
```

we can achieve the same by:

```
Math.min.apply(null, arr)
```

Comment: Use `sort()` or `map()` and why are your numbers strings?

Comment: @epascarello: sorry typo mistake, they are numbers.
do sort method works with the array containing objects ?

Comment: Here's the detail you need to make it work @robieee http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript

Comment: Why don't you want to use a for loop?

Comment: @DanielRobinson: There are many good reasons to avoid `for`-loops.  Chief among then is the fact that they do little to express programmer intent, focusing instead on mostly irrelevant bookkeeping instructions to the computer.  This video explains fairly well: http://vimeo.com/43382919

Comment: In many cases, I would agree. But for this example, compare how it would be done with a `for` loop to my answer below that uses `reduce`. Is the latter really that much less concerned with irrelevant bookkeeping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@antyrat's solution is more explicit, but I figured I'd provide another way:

```
var people=[{name: 'john', age: 23}, {name: 'jonny', age: 27}, {name: 'roony', age: 13}, {name: 'david', age: 33}];

var youngestPerson = people.reduce(function(youngestPerson, person){
    return person.age < youngestPerson.age ? person : youngestPerson; 
}, people[0]);

console.log(youngestPerson);
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use reduce:

```
min = tempArr.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
    return (currentValue.age < previousValue.age ? currentValue : previousValue);
});
```

Any solution involving sort will be suboptimal.

Comment: Keep forgetting about reduce. +1

Comment: @Daniel Robinson: Why would sort be sub-optimal?

Comment: Finding the minimum only requires n comparisons.  Sorting requires more than that. (Quicksort, for example, requires n log n comparisons in the average case, and n^2 comparisons in the worst case).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method:

```js
var tempArr = [{name: 'john', age: '23'}, {name: 'jonny', age: '27'}, {name: 'roony', age: '13'}, {name: 'david', age: '33'}];
tempArr = tempArr.sort( function( a, b ) {
    var AgeA = parseInt( a.age, 10 );
    var AgeB = parseInt( b.age, 10 )
    if ( AgeA < AgeB ) return -1;
    else if ( AgeA > AgeB ) return 1;
    else return 0;
});
console.log(tempArr);
console.log(tempArr[0]); // is the record with smallest `age` value
```

Comment: Sorting is a very inefficient way to find a minimum value, and a for loop would be less code.